# How to check if file download is complete

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is download a file from a web page. Once the file is done downloading, I'll have it print something to the screen.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Uri remoteUri = new Uri("http://soundcloud.com/dubstep/spag-heddy-the-master-vip/download");
        string fileName1 = "t", myStringWebResource = null;

        // Create a new WebClient instance.
        using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName1;
            // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
            myWebClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Url1_DownloadStringCompleted);
            myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(remoteUri, fileName1);

        }
}
public static void Url1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;
        yes();
    }
    public static void yes()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RRRR");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Where I run in to a problem is with `myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(remoteUri, fileName1);` I'm not sure what I should have there instead of what is there. I have also verified that `myWebClient.DownloadFile` works.

Comment: Why can't you just use the blocking DownloadFile method?

Comment: @PaulK: Agree, but I also know that there are environments where the sync methods don't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Worked when I made these changes to the code: Changed input string to URI, fixed local path, used the correct eventhandler and did Console.Read in the end. I have shortened the code a bit, but you get the idea:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
    {
        myWebClient.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
        myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://someUrl"), @"e:\file.mp3");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
```

Comment: okay, that works now, but as soon as i run it it just opens and closes. (console app) how would i get it to fire the download completed event?

Comment: @MichaelLapan Put `Console.ReadLine()` After `myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(remoteUri, fileName1); }`

Comment: @Cyral did that, still did not fire the event. i did get it enough time to download the file.

Comment: Yes this function is not enough 'm downloading image and then cryting that in this function but when i try to crypt this file actually file not downloaded exactly and my app is crashing